# How to use Google Identity Toolkit without “Email” option in android

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

How to use Google Identity Toolkit without “Email” option in android
Need to implement Google+ and facebook only

Comment: What have you tried to discover the solution for yourself? What are you not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your imported module's resource folder,Their you can find the xml files used for creating the dialog.If you don't want the Gmail part you can make the visibility of the root tag like this `android:visibility="gone"` or you can customize the look and feel.Please try this,hope this will help you.